# option to send copy of customer welcome email to another address mail in magento 2

Tags: magento, module, cc, bcc

i need to send a copy of **welcome email to specific mail**.

what i did is i tried to create module to do it **programmatically**, i created a overrid that handle execute CreatePost.php but it sent before.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Cinemanext, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Cinemanext\ForceLogin\Controller\Account;

use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{

}
```

this option exist in order mail, you can send copy to specific email.

[image: send order mail copy]

how i can add same function to welcome mail.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php
namespace Cinemanext\ForceLogin\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class CreatePost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory
     */
    protected $addressFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $escaper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory
     */
    protected $urlFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
     */
    private $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param AddressFactory $addressFactory
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param UrlFactory $urlFactory
     * @param Session $session
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        AddressFactory $addressFactory,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        Escaper $escaper,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        Session $session,
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
        $this->addressFactory   = $addressFactory;
        $this->messageManager   = $messageManager;
        $this->escaper          = $escaper;
        $this->urlModel         = $urlFactory->create();
        $this->session          = $session;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);

        // messageManager can also be set via $context
        // $this->messageManager   = $context->getMessageManager();

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        // if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->registration->isAllowed()) {
        //     $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        //     return $resultRedirect;
        // }

        // check if the form is actually posted and has the proper form key
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($url));
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

        $firstName = 'John';
        $lastName = 'Doe';
        $email = 'johndoe4@example.com';
        $password = 'Test1234';

        // instantiate customer object
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        // check if customer is already present
        // if customer is already present, then show error message
        // else create new customer
        if ($customer->loadByEmail($email)->getId()) {
            //echo 'Customer with the email ' . $email . ' is already registered.';
            $message = __(
                'There is already an account with this email address "%1".',
                $email
            );
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            $this->messageManager->addError($message);
        } else {
            try {
                // prepare customer data
                $customer->setEmail($email); 
                $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
                $customer->setLastname($lastName);

                // set null to auto-generate password
                $customer->setPassword($password); 

                // set the customer as confirmed
                // this is optional
                // comment out this line if you want to send confirmation email
                // to customer before finalizing his/her account creation
                $customer->setForceConfirmed(true);

                // save data
                $customer->save();

                // save customer address
                // this is optional
                // you can skip saving customer address while creating the customer
                $customerAddress = $this->addressFactory->create();                
                $customerAddress->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                                ->setFirstname($firstName)
                                ->setLastname($lastName)
                                ->setCountryId('US')
                                ->setRegionId('12') // optional, depends upon Country, e.g. USA
                                ->setRegion('California') // optional, depends upon Country, e.g. USA
                                ->setPostcode('90232')
                                ->setCity('Culver City')
                                ->setTelephone('888-888-8888')
                                ->setFax('999')
                                ->setCompany('XYZ')
                                ->setStreet(array(
                                    '0' => 'Your Customer Address 1', // compulsory
                                    '1' => 'Your Customer Address 2' // optional
                                )) 
                                ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                                ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                                ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

                try {
                    // save customer address
                    $customerAddress->save();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer address.'));
                }                

                // send welcome email to the customer
                $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();

                //echo 'Customer with the email ' . $email . ' is successfully created.';

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __(
                        'Customer account with email %1 created successfully.',
                        $email
                    )
                );

                $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($url));

                //$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
                return $resultRedirect;
            } catch (StateException $e) {
                $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%1">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.',
                    $url
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
            } catch (InputException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($e->getErrors() as $error) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($error->getMessage()));
                }
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
            }
        }

        $this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
        $defaultUrl = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($defaultUrl));
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: but this is the original magento CreatePost class, 
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
this send just default welcome email, how to add Cc or Bcc to send to someone else

Comment: check this file \vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\EmailNotification.php you have to override it in your custom extension